# Dax Measure Count Last Entry for each Order

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have two tables:
Sales Header

```
Order Nr    Date        Value
258         01.01.2021  50
98          01.01.2021  40
```

This table contains some basic information per order.
Then I have a transactional table, with the routing per order:

```
Order Nr    Step    Quantity
258         01      50
258         02      50
258         03      50
258         04      50
98          01      50
```

Now I would like to get a matrix that shows me per Step how many orders have as the last entry the corresponding step. Something like:

```
Order 01  02  03  04
258                1
98     1
Total  1   0   0   1
```

How would you do that?

Here is a sample file:
https://www.file-upload.net/download-14585836/LastEntry.pbix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative solution, this a pure DAX solution.

Steps:

1. Find the max step for each order
2. Store in `SelectedStep` the Step from the current filter context.
3. If those two from above are the same, retrieve 1, otherwise 0.

```
Count =
VAR MaxStep =
    MAXX ( CALCULATETABLE ( 'Table', REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Table'[Step] ) ), [Step] )
VAR SelectedStep =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Step] )
VAR Result =
    IF ( SelectedStep = MaxStep, 1, 0 )
RETURN
    Result
```

### Output

[image]

### Table

| Order Nr | Step | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 258 | 1 | 50 |
| 258 | 2 | 50 |
| 258 | 3 | 50 |
| 258 | 4 | 50 |
| 98 | 1 | 50 |

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To achieve the desired matrix you need to follow the following steps:

1. Create a calculated column that returns the highest step no. for a given order no.

   ```
   Path Length =
   VAR order_no = 'Table'[order no]
   RETURN
       MAXX (
           FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[order no] = order_no ),
           'Table'[Step]
           )
   ```
2. Create another calculated column that returns 1 when the Path Length is the same as the highest step value for a given order no. otherwise, it returns a blank value.

   ```
   Comp = 
       IF ( 'Table'[Step] = 'Table'[Path Length], 1, BLANK () )
   ```
3. Now create a matrix with *order no as Rows*, *Step as Columns* and *measure Comp as Values* in it.
4. Right-click on the step in columns and enable the *Show items with no data* option. You should get the desired result.